# How to make my app delay and update the layout's components in every iteration of a loop

Tags: java, android

I am making a board game were I have 3 AI players and a user playing. When the user presses a Button to give its turn up to the AI's I want to add a delay so the user can see every move each AI makes.

I have tried a thread sleep and handler but it seems they are unable to update the board and add a delay with each iteration of the while loop. The code without any attempt to add a delay can be found below. I would need to add a delay after the inner while loop terminates.

```
public void onClickNextTurn(View view){
    boolean turnFinished;
    findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTurn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    while (this.playerTurn<4) {
        this.playerTurn++;
        turnFinished=false;
        while (!turnFinished) {
            diceRoll();
            MoveTriplet result = ai[playerTurn-2].aiTurn(this.boardPieceLocations, this.homeLocations, this.finishLocations, this.roll, playerTurn);
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.getMoveType() == 'b') { //The Artificial Opponent is moving from one home location to the board AND gets to roll again
                    this.homeLocations[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()] = 0;
                    if (this.boardPieceLocations[result.getNextIndex()] != 0)
                        returnPieceHome(this.boardPieceLocations[result.getNextIndex()]);
                    this.boardPieceLocations[result.getNextIndex()] = this.playerTurn;
                    this.homeButtons[playerTurn - 1][result.getPreviousIndex()].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHoles));
                    this.buttons[result.getNextIndex()].setBackgroundColor(colors[playerTurn - 1]);
                }
```

So if anyone could point me in the right direction on how I could add an delay between iterations of the outer while loop and at the same time updating the my board. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the standard Android animation APIs.  Those should handle the timing for you and be smoother anyways -- plus, they'll use the GPU more efficiently for you.